# Why doesn't this solution for ethernaut work?

Tags: fallback-function, function-selector

I am working on the ethernaut CTF level (code below)...I need to take over ownership of the instance (it's been deployed). I thought I could do it by sending a small amount of ETH to the instance address with the hex data being the encoded function selector for pwn(). Since the fallback function does a delegatecall to the delegate contract using whatever msgdata is included with the call.

But I've tried it and it doesn't work. [Here is my tx](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0xa300a449935f2318a0cf7ece40d10f1a55bd12545b5e41652dd29b4d7497cc52) Note that it fails from contract execution not out of gas

Why does this not work?

Here is the contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Delegate {

  address public owner;

  constructor(address _owner) {
    owner = _owner;
  }

  function pwn() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }
}

contract Delegation {

  address public owner;
  Delegate delegate;

  constructor(address _delegateAddress) {
    delegate = Delegate(_delegateAddress);
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  fallback() external {
    (bool result,) = address(delegate).delegatecall(msg.data);
    if (result) {
      this;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: why do you send eth in your transaction? fallback isn't payable here